# How to get data from different google form sections into a spreadsheet using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need to create a form, with different sections based on a question - and record all the responses - from the main form and its sections into a google spreadsheet. How can I do that? Are there any tutorials I can follow for google app scripts for forms and spreadsheets?

Comment: I don't use forms all that much.  Do different form sections get submitted at different times or do they all get submitted at one time.  If the answer is that they all get submitted at once then it will be in either values or namedValue of the onFormSubmit event object

Comment: @Cooper - Thanks, I was able to figure it out - Each section is a form item, and all the responses are recorded in the same response object (form.getResponses()[formResponseIndex].getItemResponses()) - We can just iterate over this to get all the responses.